# Modal will not open when clicked

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My When attempting to click the model on my webpage under the "Reserve Campsite Button" nothing seems to open ive attempted to see if the divs was causing the problem and i dont think that anything is off there. I am student so maybe there is something that i am missing or not understanding any help would be awesome thanks in advance

```html
<div id="reserveModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" class="modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header bg-info text-white">
                    <h3 class="modal-title">Reserve a Campsite</h3>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
             <form>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="numCampers" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Number of Campers</label>
            <div class="col">
          
          <select  class="form-control" name="numCampers" id="numCampers">
            <option>Select...</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="date" class="col col-sm-6 col-form-label">Date</label>
        <div class="col">
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="date" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Campsite Type</label>
        <div class="col-2 btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-success active">
              <input type="radio" name="siteTent" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Tent
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="siteRV" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> RV
              </label>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group row">
                <button type="submit" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-secondary">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark sticky-top">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" height="30" width="30"/>
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nucampNavbar"> 
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nucampNavbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg"></i> Home</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link"href="aboutus.html"><i class="fa fa-info"></i> About </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-list fa-lg"></i> Sites</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.html"><i class="fa fa-address-card fa-lg"></i> Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <span class="navbar-text ml-auto">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginmodal">
        <i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login
        </a>  
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What version of BS? Have you checked your console for errors? Note also that your HTML is malformed and you need to correct the structure. Try running it through a HTML validator.

Answer (score 0):

Just search bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/) on modals:
Their implementation of a modal is as so:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However I can't see any option to toggle the modal? Only a log-in modal, which has a different data-target than the modal id.

Answer (score 0):

Button did not have data-toggle='modal' there was also not a data-target linking to the id of#reserveModal. corrected code below:

```
<a href="#reserveForm" role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg text-nowrap" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reserveModal" >Reserve Campsite</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).